# How to Limit Data or Option in select2 jquery?

Tags: jquery

This is my html select box

```
   <select id=""countries>
   <option>Select Country</option>     
   </select>
```

This is my script file

I am using this https://select2.org/ select2 for select box.
So there may be many data so i want to limit some few country at first.But when i start search i can get any country i want.so How should do ?

```
       data.countries.forEach(function (country) {
            $("#countries").select2({
             
           });
            var newOption = new Option(country.name, country.id, false, false);
            $('#countries').append(newOption).trigger('change');

        });
```

Example

```
<select>
   <option>USA</option>
   <option>UK</option>
   <option>China</option>
   <option>Russia</option>
   <option>Mexico</option>
   <option>Bangladesh</option>
   <option>Pakistan</option>
   <option>India</option>
   <option>Bhutan</option>
   <option>France</option>
   <option>Portugual</option>
   <option>Uruguay</option>
   <option>Argentina</option>
   <option>Wales</option>
   <option>Finland</option>
   <option>Thailan</option>
</select>
```

From All these country  i want to show only 4 country but when user search country name like India then it return result

```
<select>
   <option>USA</option>
   <option>UK</option>
   <option>China</option>
   <option>Russia</option>
</select
```

Comment: Please create a minimal runnable example.

Comment: @Reporter i have given example .Hope you understand